Using font-latex-user-keyword-classes
I'd like to add a few faces that should be used to color macros and commands in LaTeX-mode. Following the documentation, I found the variable font-latex-user-keyword-classes, which is supposed to do exactly that, but I find its documentation a bit imprecise, and when I do what I think I'm supposed to, nothing happens. For instance, I'd like to have text like in \blue{text} to be colored blue, so I put the following at the end of the .el-file corresponding to my default LaTeX-package cttools:
(defface blue-face '((((class color) (min-colors 8)) :foreground "blue"))
  "A generic blue face.")

(add-to-list 'font-latex-user-keyword-classes
             '((color '(("blue" "{")) 'blue-face "command")))

What I'm not clear about from the documentation is whether the name of the class, in this case color, is supposed to be a string or not. In any case, the documentation for font-latex-user-keyword-classes says that setting this variable directly doesn't have an effect and I should restart Emacs, so to test if it works I started a new instance of Emacs and opened a test file
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cttools}
 
\title{test}

\author{Alexander Prähauser}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\blue{taal}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:

However, when I do that, taal doesn't appear blue. Yet, I checked that font-latex-user-keyword-classes has the value it should and blue-face is indeed listed as a blue face by list-faces-display. So why doesn't it work?

I found out how it works, I think. The correct format is
 '(font-latex-user-keyword-classes
   '(("blue-generic" (("blue" "{")) blue-generic command)))

But it only seems to work if it is put into custom-set-variables, any declarations later than that, for instance in my cttools.el-file, didn't seem to have any effect.

Yes; this is due to the :set keyword.  If you have a recent Emacs and don't like the custom interface, you can try the macro setopt for setting the variable.
